# simultaneously update hundreds of sites on the same server

Tags: php, permissions, synchronization, ssh

I'm working on a Hostgator dedicated server where there are hundreds of sites that have similarities in file structure and .php files common to each site.

I would like to be able to work on just one site (a "model" site) and then sync those changes across all the other sites. I am open to either having this happen automatically or semi-manually (running a script or command.) *One requirement is that since a few sites are different they would need to be excluded from this sync.* What are some techniques for achieving this? Here is what I have thought of so far...

- `RSync` : is rsync capable of this? I
  have never used it but heard it is
  great for copying files from one server location to another.
- `SSH` : I am not super comfortable
  working with shell commands but I can
  imagine this is definitely the
  "proper" place to be making these
  kinds of changes. (not sure how to
  loop and make changes though all
  directories EXCEPT the few that are different)
- `PHP` : If possible I'd love to be
  able to do this with PHP except my server uses SuPHP for security and I can't really get around the permissions it requires. I may be able to switch to fcgi though... (open to suggestions for this also)

My file structure is as follows:

```
    /home/model/
    /home/site1/
    /home/site2/
    /home/site3/
    /home/exception/
    /home/site5/
    /home/site6/
    /home/exception/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash commands are more suitable and tends to be easier,
such has combine `rysnc` plus symbolic links `ln`

In nutshell,

```
ln -s /home/model/ /home/site1 
ln -s /home/model/ /home/site2
ln -s /home/model/ /home/site3
```

so, it will soft-link site1,site2,site3 to model

what is symbolic link ?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link

After that, you just need to **rsync** your changes to directory model,
and changes will immediately apply to site1,site2,site3
(because all directories are symbolic link to model)

as for site5, site6, since is difference, [scp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy) fit the shoe better.

Comment: ah very cool approach @ajreal. The issue with the symlinks though would be that the sites aren't completely identical, they all have the same structure however many of the files are unique. What I'm really looking for is a way to add a directory to every single site or update a few files throughout all the sites easily. Looking into scp now.

Comment: +1 symbolic links are definitely better choice, than actually syncing the files.

Comment: @Ish Kumar maybe I am misunderstanding symbolic links, but if I have the entire `/site1/`, `/site2/` directories symlinks to `/model/` how would I store unique files within these symlinked directories? On the other hand, if I only symlink the common files and directories, how would I for example add a directory to each site? Thanks

Comment: @filip, You should softlink site1/common/ -> model/common and keep site1/unique_files as physical files. So in future if you ever need need to update common files just edit model/common

Comment: Thanks @Ish Kumar that makes sense, however may be tough to implement at this point. Curious if anyone has other suggestions